# ASP.NET CORE 2 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Whenever uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-core

I always receive the following error message when I try to upload file via IIS/Server, it works locally but on the server, it always has this problem.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem?

Error Message:

> Failed invoking event handler:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitable.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.ProcessReceives()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()    at
>   System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)    at
>   System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()    at
>   System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.PumpAsync()
>   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()    at
>   System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)    at
>   System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)    at
>   System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ReadAsync(Memory`1
>   buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1
>   buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()    at
>   System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()    at
>   Sentry.Extensibility.DefaultRequestPayloadExtractor.DoExtractPayLoad(IHttpRequest
>   request)    at
>   Sentry.Extensibility.BaseRequestPayloadExtractor.ExtractPayload(IHttpRequest
>   request)    at
>   Sentry.Extensibility.RequestBodyExtractionDispatcher.ExtractPayload(IHttpRequest
>   request)    at Sentry.AspNetCore.ScopeExtensions.SetBody(BaseScope
>   scope, HttpContext context, SentryAspNetCoreOptions options)    at
>   Sentry.AspNetCore.ScopeExtensions.Populate(Scope scope, HttpContext
>   context, SentryAspNetCoreOptions options)    at
>   Sentry.AspNetCore.SentryMiddleware.PopulateScope(HttpContext context,
>   Scope scope)    at Sentry.Scope.Evaluate()

Code-Behind

```
try
{
    string folder = "FileLocation/";
    string folderpath = "";

    if (model.Filess != null)
    {
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.Filess.FileName);
        fileExtension = fileExtension.ToLower();

        long fileSize = model.Filess.Length;

        if (fileSize <= 10485760)
        {
            folderpath = Path.Combine(__hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads", folder);
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderpath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
            }

            var parsedContentDisposition =
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(model.Filess.ContentDisposition);

            var filename = Path.Combine(__hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath,
                "Uploads", folder, parsedContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'));

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filename))
            {
                await model.Filess.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/pull/2562), the MSFT has fixed this issue on asp.net core 2.1. I suggest you could try to update your asp.net core runtime version(to 2.2) on your server.

I aslo created a test demo on my side and publish to the IIS server, it works well.

More detais about my test demo, you could refer to below codes:

MVC View:

```
@model  UploadViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>


<form asp-action="CreateAsync" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="Id" /> 
    <input asp-for="Filess" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MVCCoreUpload.Models;

namespace MVCCoreUpload.Controllers
{
    public class FileUploadController : Controller
    {

        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public FileUploadController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new UploadViewModel());
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(UploadViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                string folder = "FileLocation/";
                string folderpath = "";

                if (model.Filess != null)
                {
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.Filess.FileName);
                    fileExtension = fileExtension.ToLower();

                    long fileSize = model.Filess.Length;

                    if (fileSize <= 10485760)
                    {
                        folderpath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads", folder);
                        if (!Directory.Exists(folderpath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
                        }

                        var parsedContentDisposition =
                            ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(model.Filess.ContentDisposition);

                        var filename = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath,
                            "Uploads", folder, parsedContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'));

                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filename))
                        {
                            await model.Filess.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return View("index");
        }
    }
}
```